# Is there any way in vim to jump to lines with certain number of occurences of a character?

Tags: html, vim

I am trying to use a macro and I would need to jump to lines only with certain number of occurred characters. Why I need this? I want to make modifications in a HTML code, but only on lines where the div class attribute is set and nothing else.

So match these:

```
<div class="div_class"></div>
```

And don't want to match these:

```
<div class="div_class" style="width: 100px"></div>
```

It is a boilerplate code, that is why I need to restructure it. I was thinking of matching lines in a macro with only two "'s. I can accept other alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about: `/\vclass\="(\w|\s|-)*"\s*\>`

This will match:

`<div class="div_class"></div>`

`<div class="div_class asdf"></div>`

`<div class="div_class asdf spinal-classname"></div>`